# Por qué este bucle no devuelve nada y si lo hace en otra función

Tags: javascript

Juro que he estado mirandolo durante 5 minutos sin apartar la vista y no logro encontrar que es lo que cambia....

En esta función el bucle for devuelve correctamente el primer numero que coincide entre dos arrays:

```js
function checking(){
var array1 = [3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 24, 27, 30, 33, 36, 39, 42, 45, 48];
var array2 = [4, 8, 12, 16, 20, 24, 28, 32, 36, 40, 44, 48];

for (number in array1){
 for (num in array2){
 if (array2[num] === array1[number]){
  return array2[num]}
 }
}

}

checking() // Devuelve correctamente 12
```

Sin embargo en esta, que lo unico que hago es copiar y pegar el bucle dentro de la función `smallestCommons(arr)` no hace nada:

```js
function smallestCommons(arr) {
   var array1 = []
   var array2 = []
  var numbers = [];
      for (var i=2; i < 50; i++){
        numbers.push(i)}

 var multiplesOf = (numbers, multiple) => {
        return numbers.filter(x => x % multiple === 0);
        }
 array1.push(multiplesOf(numbers, arr[0]))
 array2.push(multiplesOf(numbers, arr[1]))
 

  // A partir de aquí porque este bucle no devuelve nada:
   for (number in array1){
  for (num in array2){
  if (array2[num] === array1[number]){
   return array2[num]}
            }
        }
        
}

smallestCommons([3,4]);
```

Los números en los array son los mismos en ambas funciones

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema está en que declaras los arrays: `array1` y `array2` y luego les haces un `push` de otro array, es decir, que tus arrays son arrays de una posición donde el único valor es el array que quieres, por lo tanto, la solución más directa sería dar el valor del resultado de `multiplesOf` a los respectivos arrays, no añadirles un valor.

```js
function smallestCommons(arr) {
  var numbers = [];
      for (var i=2; i < 50; i++){
        numbers.push(i)}

 var multiplesOf = (numbers, multiple) => {
        return numbers.filter(x => x % multiple === 0);
        }
 array1 = multiplesOf(numbers, arr[0]);
 array2 = multiplesOf(numbers, arr[1]);

  // A partir de aquí porque este bucle no devuelve nada:
   for (number in array1){
  for (num in array2){
  if (array2[num] === array1[number]){
   return array2[num]}
            }
        }
        
}

console.log(smallestCommons([3,4]));
```

Comment: Entiendo, o sea que realmente después de hacer push de un array entero a un array vacío es como si he creado dentro de array1 dos arrays, no?

Comment: @JavierCake hacer `push` en un array es una de las operaciones básicas que tiene el array y sí, es añadir al final de este, un valor